# Managing Progress Bars for Multiple File Upload

Tags: javascript, html, progress

So I am using a ajax to upload multiple files. Everything seems to be working like a charm... I just can't get to make my progress bars to work ...

Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks.

```
var images = document.getElementById('images');
for(var i=0;i<images.files.length;i++) {
    var formData = new FormData();
    var image = images.files[i];
    formData.append('image', image);
    formData.append('order_id', document.getElementById('order_id').value);

    var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open("POST","/pictures/uploadImage");
    xmlhttp.send(formData);
    xmlhttp.upload.addEventListener('progress', function(e){
        document.getElementById("image_"+i+"_progress").value = Math.ceil(e.loaded/e.total)*100;
    }, false);
}
```

I am basically uploading images individually .. I figured that would help me track the progress bars better ... Perhaps there's another approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [MDN][1]:

> Note: You need to add the event listeners before calling open() on the request.  Otherwise the progress events will not fire.

So, combining this knowledge with Engin's answer, you could do like this:

```js
const images = document.getElementById('images');
const completedCount = 0; // added for loadend scenario
const length = images.files.length;

for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    const formData = new FormData();
    const image = images.files[i];
    formData.append('image', image);
    formData.append('order_id', document.getElementById('order_id').value);

    const xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    (elId => {
        xmlhttp.upload.addEventListener('progress', e => {
            document.getElementById('image_' + elId + '_progress').value = Math.ceil(e.loaded / e.total) * 100;
        }, false);
    })(i); // to unbind i.

    // --- added for loadend scenario. ---
    xmlhttp.addEventListener('loadend', () => {
        completedCount++;
        if (completedCount == length) {
            // here you should hide your gif animation
        }
    }, false);
    // ---
    xmlhttp.open('POST', '/pictures/uploadImage');
    xmlhttp.send(formData);
}
```

#### UPDATE:

To catch the event when all files are uploaded you may use `loadend` events. I've updated my code (see comments), I'm not sure this is a correct way though.
[1]: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest#Monitoring_progress

Comment: I have a followup question, say I am uploading 8 files how can I structure an event listener to fire once all those files are completed uploading. Basically I am going to replace my submit button with a loading gif. Once all the files are uploaded I want to stop that loading gif - and change that with something that says "DONE". Thanks.

Comment: I've updated my answer, although I'm not sure this is the best approach and I haven't tested it.

Answer (score 1):

i did not try but i think it works, because for loop finished before your post and "i"s value equal to images.files.length. sorry for terrible english

**try this:**

```
var images = document.getElementById('images');

for(var i=0;i<images.files.length;i++) {
    getProgress(images.files[i],i); 
}

function getProgress(image,order){
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('image', image);
    formData.append('order_id', document.getElementById('order_id').value);

    var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open("POST","/pictures/uploadImage");
    xmlhttp.send(formData);
    xmlhttp.upload.addEventListener('progress', function(e){
        document.getElementById("image_"+order+"_progress").value = Math.ceil(e.loaded/e.total)*100;
    }, false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can include another function.

```
function upload(ProgressbarId){

    /*
     .
     .
     .
     some code
    */

    xmlhttp.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(evt){uploadProgress(evt,ProgressbarId);}, false);

}


function uploadProgress(evt,ProgressbarId) {

    if (evt.lengthComputable) {
        var percentComplete = Math.round(evt.loaded * 100 / evt.total);
        set_Progressbar(ProgressbarId,percentComplete);
    }
}
```

}